# VBA - Having issue getting code onto multiple sheets and updating tables

Tags: excel, vba

I am pulling data from a database.  There is a lot of data that I have to split apart and bring back together because of poor initial entry into the database or the database transfer software repeating information it shouldn't be, in order to get something useable.  One of the many issues I'm running into is getting a trim command run on multiple (2) sheets.  I can run the code on the initial sheet where my command button is fine, but I'm having problems getting it to also run on a separate worksheet.  I'm also having issues getting my tables, power pivot and my pivot tables to update in the correct order.

Code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Range("b1:b5").Select
Application.Run "SSGenALLQueryDetail"
Dim r As Range
Set r = Intersect(Range("E1").EntireColumn, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
r.Value = Evaluate("IF(ROW(" & r.Address & "),IF(" & r.Address & "<>"""",TRIM(" & r.Address & "),""""))")
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
Worksheets("JC by Phase and Cost Type").Activate

End Sub
```

The application updates the tables, and that works fine.

Both columns that need to be trimmed are in column E.  The entire column has to be trimmed.  This is the section of code I'd like to run on both the current worksheet (Called "Item Data Sheet") and the worksheet "Data Sheet":

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = Intersect(Range("E1").EntireColumn, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
r.Value = Evaluate("IF(ROW(" & r.Address & "),IF(" & r.Address & "<>"""",TRIM(" & r.Address & "),""""))")
```

Finally, the "activeworkbook.refreshall" command is to update my power pivot and pivot tables.  Sometimes it works and sometimes doesn't depending on the code I'm trying out (and believe me, I've tried a lot).  I'd prefer to use it, because it's simple.  First I have to update my power pivot tables.  Then I have pivot tables on 2 separate worksheets and 1 has to be updated before the other.  The first one that has to be updated is on the worksheet "ActualUnit Adj" and the second one has to be on "JC by Phase and Cost Type".  There are several worksheets with charts afterwards, but those can be updated in any order afterwards.

I have tried selecting multiple sheets and running the code on the selected sheets, I have tried using an array for selected sheets.  I'm most likely just messing up the code because I have no formal training and this is all just google searched code that I'm slapping together in hopes that it works.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you pulling the data from the database?

Comment: It's the SSGenALLQueryDetail application.  It's through a program called spreadsheet server and query designer that allow us to access our Viewpoint Vista data base.  Query designer is basically a sequel builder that's made for non programers.  I can pull tables into the program, drag and drop and write basic code in it.  That then gets accessed by spreadsheet server, an excel add in.  That information gets dumped into my tables and then those tables are accessed by pivot tables.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following might help solve the first part of your problem

```
Public Sub TryThis()
   FixAnySheet ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Item Data Sheet")
   FixAnySheet ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data Sheet")
End Sub

Public Sub FixAnySheet(dSht As Worksheet)
   dSht.Range("b1:b5").Select
   Application.Run "SSGenALLQueryDetail"
   
   Dim r As Range
   
   Set r = Intersect(Range("E1").EntireColumn, dSht.UsedRange)
   r.Value = Evaluate("IF(ROW(" & r.Address & "),IF(" & r.Address & "<>"""",TRIM(" & r.Address & "),""""))")
   ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
   Worksheets("JC by Phase and Cost Type").Activate
End Sub
```

There are only 2 changes to your own code in the FixAnySheet routine

**Added Later :**  Using .Select isn't best practice and might well cause problems in the first line of FixAnySheet.  You may need to add a New 1st line into FixAnySheet as follows

```
dSht.Activate
```

Which may cause problems elsewhere in your code

Answer (score 0):

This is untetested, but should point you in the right direction.

Read code's comments and adjust it to fit your needs.

Let me know how it goes

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    
    ' Run a procedure (you can use just SSGenALLQueryDetail without quotes or anything else if the procedure is declared as public)
    Application.Run "SSGenALLQueryDetail"
    
    ' Declare and set a target sheet
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TargetSheetName") ' <- Replace TargetSheetName with the sheet name
        
    ' Declare and set the range you're going to work with
    Dim targetRange As Range
    Set targetRange = Intersect(targetSheet.Range("E1").EntireColumn, targetSheet.UsedRange)
        
    ' Return trimmed value
    targetRange.Value = Evaluate("IF(ROW(" & targetRange.Address & "),IF(" & targetRange.Address & "<>"""",TRIM(" & targetRange.Address & "),""""))")
    
    ' Check if you need to refresh the active workbook or the workbook running the code (if the latter, use ThisWorkbook
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
    
    ' Activate a sheet in the workbook running the code
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("JC by Phase and Cost Type").Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: This one threw me through a bit of a loop.  What I did was copy the 'set targetsheet ='  down one line and just filled in my target sheets.  What ended up happening was that none of my columns got trimmed and on the second workshet, one of the columns got replaced with the first worksheet where the command button is located's cell contents.  ` ` `    ' Declare and set a target sheet
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet 1") ' <- Replace TargetSheetName with the sheet name.
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet 2") ' <- Replace TargetSheetName with the` ` `

Answer (score 0):

What I was doing was trying to hit a screw with a hammer.  Instead of putting the trimming function into a vba code, I ended up putting the trimming function into the table.  The program I'm using to pull data in from the data base allows me to maintain formulas at the end of the tables.  This got rid of the lions share of my issue.  Once i had the extra code out of my command button, refreshing the workbook worked flawlessly.  Sometimes simpler is better.  I'd show a picture but I'm not allowed to yet.  It really turned out well and the people here gave me the direction I needed to slog through it and get a professional and easy to use report available for use.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30144070)